# SharePoint 2010 document Library - Permission based on column value

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

I have a document library which includes "department" column amongst others. My requirement is

- Assign permission in the document upload process depending on which department should have access to this document
- Depending on which department a user belongs and also what permission the user has, the view of the document library should be filtered to the documents the user has access to rather than showing everything.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is to break the inheritance and give item level permission. You can do this in event receiver.